# Evaluating $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\sin(\ln(x))}}{1+\sqrt nx^{42}}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am asked to calculate

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\sin(\ln(x))}}{1+\sqrt nx^{42}}dx $$
It looks like it goes to $0$.

> **I tried**
>
> $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{\sin(\ln(x))}}{1+\sqrt nx^{42}}dx \le \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{1}}{1+\sqrt nx^{42}}dx = e\cdot\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+\sqrt nx^{42}}dx = e \cdot \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+\sqrt n \cdot (x^{21})^{2}}dx$

First I tried the MCT to get that limes into the integral but MCT cant be used here.

Now I know that $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \arctan$ but I am not really sure on how to use it here.

Any help is appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $u=n^{1/84}x$ so that $du=n^{1/84}dx$ and the integral equals:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{\sin(\ln(x))}}{1+\sqrt[]{n}x^{42}}\, dx = \int^\infty_0\frac{1}{n^{1/84}} \frac{\exp\left( \sin(\ln(un^{-1/84}))\right)}{1+u^{42}}\, du 
\end{align}
You know that $\exp\left( \sin(\ln(un^{-1/84}))\right)\leq e$, hence:
\begin{align}
\bigg | \frac{1}{n^{1/84}} \frac{\exp\left( \sin(\ln(un^{-1/84}))\right)}{1+u^{42}}\bigg| \leq \frac{e}{1+u^{42}}
\end{align}
Furthermore
 $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e}{1+u^{42}}du<\infty$$
By DCT we have:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{\sin(\ln(x))}}{1+\sqrt[]{n}x^{42}}\, dx=\int^\infty_0 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/84}} \frac{\exp\left( \sin(\ln(un^{-1/84}))\right)}{1+u^{42}}\, du  =  0 
\end{align}

Comment: Ahh I didnt even think about substituting. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{e^{\sin(\ln x)}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\right|&\leq\left|\dfrac{e^{\sin(\ln x)}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\chi_{0< x\leq 1}(x)\right|+\left|\dfrac{e^{\sin(\ln x)}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\chi_{x>1}(x)\right|\\
&\leq\dfrac{e}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\chi_{0< x\leq 1}(x)+\dfrac{e}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\chi_{x>1}(x)\\
&\leq e\cdot\chi_{0< x\leq 1}(x)+\dfrac{e}{1+x^{42}}\chi_{x>1}(x),
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e\cdot\chi_{0< x\leq 1}(x)+\dfrac{e}{1+x^{42}}\chi_{x>1}(x)dx=e+e\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+x^{42}}dx<\infty,
\end{align*}
so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem applies.

Comment: Actually one does not have to split the interval $(0,\infty)$, see @robjohn answer.

Answer (score 0):

When $x\gt0$,
$$
\left|\frac{e^{\sin(\log(x))}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\right|\le\frac{e}{1+x^{42}}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{e}{1+x^{42}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{e\pi}{42}\csc\left(\frac\pi{42}\right)
$$
converges. Furthermore, pointwise,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\sin(\log(x))}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}=0
$$
Therefore, by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{\sin(\log(x))}}{1+\sqrt{n}x^{42}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty0\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Yes, I just realised that I don't have to split the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n,$ the integrand, which is nonnegative, is bounded above on $[0,\infty)$ by $\dfrac{e}{1+\sqrt n x^{42}}.$ Letting $x = n^{-1/84}y$ shows

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+\sqrt n x^{42}}\, dx = n^{-1/84}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^{42}}\, dy.$$

The last integral is finite and $n^{-1/84}\to 0,$ so our limit is $0.$